# How should I access to AWS S3 bucket in apache beam pipeline which are located in different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have to read data from two different bucket(**bucket1 and bucket2**) which are located in different regions(**us-east-1 and us-east-2**),
The Apache beam pipeline is as follows,

```
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("*********", "************************************");
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(AwsOptions.class);
    options.setRunner(DirectRunner.class);

    options.as(AwsOptions.class).setAwsCredentialsProvider(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials));
    options.as(AwsOptions.class).setAwsRegion("us-east-1");
    options.as(AwsOptions.class).setAwsRegion("us-east-2");
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<String> bucket1Data = pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from("s3://bucket1/data/employee.txt")); // located in us-east-1 region
        PCollection<KV<Row, Row>> bucket1DataRows = bucket1Data
                .apply(ParDo.of(new MyFunction(.....)));

    PCollection<String> bucket2Data = pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from("s3://bucket2/data/employee.txt")); // located in us-east-2 region
        PCollection<KV<Row, Row>> bucket2DataRows = bucket2Data
                .apply(ParDo.of(new MyFunction(.....)));

    .... processing logics .....

    final PipelineResult result = pipeline.run();
```

The above code needs pipeline options to be set with **"us-east-1" and "us-east-2"** as we are using buckets from these regions but,with this code I get following exception:

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The
>   bucket is in this region: us-east-1. Please use this region to retry
>   the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 301
>   Moved Permanently; Request ID: 8q8egbislbcgi; S3 Extended Request ID:
>   DFV5637IYGOIUGB/9X+UKDVGILSDBC9LSUDBCLISdbCFr4=), S3 Extended Request
>   ID: KGDVCUYLVsIC.VKs/9X+SDVLCIVSdbLIHVsdI;.sbdkC+Fr4=     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4914)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4860)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1320)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3FileSystem.getObjectMetadata(S3FileSystem.java:358)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3FileSystem.matchNonGlobPath(S3FileSystem.java:365)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3FileSystem.lambda$matchNonGlobPaths$2(S3FileSystem.java:348)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.lambda$supplyAsync$0(MoreFutures.java:104)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1626)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Is there any way to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a custom `S3ClientBuilderFactory` (using the v2 module `beam-sdks-java-io-amazon-web-services2`)

```
public class GlobalAccessS3ClientBuilderFactory extends DefaultS3ClientBuilderFactory {
    @Override
    public AmazonS3ClientBuilder createBuilder(S3Options s3Options) {
        return super.createBuilder(s3Options).enableForceGlobalBucketAccess();
    }
}
```

This factory is then enabled using pipeline options (S3Options), or if preferred programmatically of course.

```
--s3ClientFactoryClass=my.GlobalAccessS3ClientBuilderFactory
```